# numpy "TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types" and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my input dataframe:

```
    F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6  F7  F8  F9  F10 F11 F12 F13 F14 F15 F16
 F1 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1
 F2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1
 F3 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
 F4 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0
 F5 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1
 F6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1
 F7 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1
 F8 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0
 F9 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
F10 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
F11 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1
F12 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1
F13 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1
F14 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1
F15 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0
F16 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
```

I want to apply this code:

```
m = df2.to_numpy()

mask = m * m[:, np.newaxis, :].transpose((0,2,1))

bol = mask.any(axis=1)

final = m | bol
```

But at the `final` step I get this error:

**TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''**

Please tell me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is an array of floats, you cannot directly perform a `A | B` operation if not both arrays are of boolean type.

Assuming you want to consider `0`/`1` as `False`/`True`, use:

```
m = df2.to_numpy().astype(bool)
```

or

```
final = m.astype(bool)|bol
```

If you only need `final` and not the intermediates, it is more efficient to convert to boolean early.

Output as integer:

```
final = (m.astype(bool)|bol).astype(int)
```

or, if early conversion of `m` to boolean:

```
# m = df2.to_numpy().astype(bool)
# ...
final = (m|bol).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight! But I want my result in 0s and 1s not in boolean

Comment: @Zaman `final = (m.astype(bool)|bol).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert values of array `m` to boolean for mapping `1/0` to `True/False`:

```
final = m.astype(bool) | bol
```

---

```
print (final)
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True False  True  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
   True  True  True  True]]
```

Last cast to integers:

```
final = (m.astype(bool) | bol).astype(int)
```

Comment: -_-" unanswered for 30 min and we both answer simultaneously⋅

Comment: @mozway - Ya, I have meeting ;)

Comment: Thanks for your insight! But I want my result in 0s and 1s not in boolean.

Comment: @Zaman - then use `final = (m.astype(bool) | bol).astype(int)`

Comment: alright! its done Thanks !!